# Shortcut with arguments in Debian

Tags: linux

I have a volume on a debian server which contains a large number of images at full resolution in various folders. What I'd like to do is have a separate sort of browse proxy folder which contains lower quality browse copies of these to enable users to access them for viewing over lower speed dial in accounts.

I'd ideally like these to be created on the fly using ImageMagick so there isnt the need to store the large number of browse copies full time and worry about keeping them up to date etc

The way I'd invisaged this happening is the browse proxy folder containing a duplicate file and folder structure but with symlinks pointing to a script to transform them with the file path as an argument. Except I know this isnt possible with symlinks so am wondering if there's another way of doing this on linux. On windows shortcuts can take arguments and I'm wondering how to do the same on a Linux platform? (or perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with symlinks, but you could be clever about it by using GNU make.

- Create a makefile that makes those thumbnails based off the master, so that only those thumbnails that don't exist or need to be updated get created
- Schedule that makefile to run once a minute, or every 5 minutes or whatever.
- Share the thumbnail directory

Comment: Something along my lines was going to be my fall back, was hoping not to have to store permenantly but perhaps easier!

Comment: It's way easier, especially given the fact that it's SIMPLE. ;)

Comment: not to mention that `convert`-ing hundreds of high resolution pictures will be slow on any computer slower than a Top500.org cluster...

Answer (score 0):

The way to have apparent directory entries that don't (directly) correspond to files stored on a disk under Linux (and several other unices) is [FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). Google doesn't turn up a fuse for image size conversions, however, so it looks like it would be a small programming project.

If always viewing through a web browser is acceptable, there are several tools that might meet your needs, such as [ansel1](http://packages.debian.org/sid/ansel1), [gallery](http://packages.debian.org/sid/gallery)/[gallery2](http://packages.debian.org/lenny-backports/gallery2), [pictor](http://launchpad.net/pictor), [webmagick](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/webmagick). I haven't used any of them.

And in fact, if you want transparent filesystem access, you can combine a web-based solution with [httpfs2](http://packages.debian.org/sid/httpfs2)…